# Interpreting a vector field in curvilinear basis vectors

Tags: vector-fields, curvilinear-coordinates

I'm having trouble understanding what this scalar field in spherical coordinates represents:

$\vec{a}(r, \theta, \phi) = 4\theta \hat{e_r} + \hat{e_{\theta}}$

Without converting the spherical basis vectors to cartesian, is it possible to visualize the vector field? How would you plot the vector at a specific point $P$ without transformation?

I understand that the spherical basis vectors change for different $(r, \theta, \phi)$, but they are still orthogonal for all $(r, \theta, \phi)$, and each basis vector points in the direction of an increasing coordinate. I also understand that you can transform to cartesian with $e_r = (cos\theta sin\phi \hat{i}, sin\theta sin\phi \hat{y}, cos\phi \hat{z})$ and so on for $e_{\theta}, e_{\phi}$.

EDIT:

Turloc's answer helped me visualize the field.

To find the basis spherical basis vectors and interpret the equation algebraically, I find myself using the transform matrix to cartesian system. Is this necessary?

Comment: re: your [recent deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4652145/242), are your familiar with rings, e.g. $\,\Bbb Z_n = $ integers $\!\bmod n,\,$ and their ideals, e.g. $\,(a,b) = c,\,$ i.e. $\,a\Bbb Z + b\Bbb Z = c\Bbb Z\,$ for $\,c = \gcd(a,b)$?

Comment: @BillDubuque, I have not worked with rings so much. But your comment looks similar to Bezout’s identity. I will add that the motivation behind my question is to avoid Bezout when formulating unique factorization. Grower talks about that in the beginning of his post in the deleted question (which I will repost shortly)

Comment: Those "direct" proofs don't really avoid Bezout's theorem, rather they essentially inline its proof, i.e. they write the proof in low-level assembly language instead of high-level language (which has the bad side-effect of obscuring the key ideas). Mathematicians spent centuries to derive these higher-order concepts to help simplify the proof so it is foolish to ignore them (here the key idea is that ideals are principal in Euclidean domains, generated by any least element). That proof of Gowers is such a direct proof, but the proof on his first-linked page is not (it uses Lagranges theorem).

Comment: @BillDubuque: that makes sense.

What seems valuable though is following the low-level process to understand the "behind-the-scenes scratch work". Even Gower says "...the order in which one thinks of a proof is not the order in which one writes it. These web pages are attempts to write proofs in their untidy, thinking order rather than their neat, logical order...Nevertheless, the process of reorganizing one's incoherent thoughts into a mathematics paper or textbook is an important one"

Would you agree?

Comment: It's a really poor presentation that only obscures the key ideas. I recommed that you ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To picture a vector field, try vector projections against the orthonormal basis. This isolates the vector's coordinate. This also varies according to the exact definition of the basis, some bases are not normalized adding a layer of complexity.

In this case $\vec{a}\cdot\hat{e_r}=4\theta$. This means that the r component points directly away from the origin starts out very small and increases as the coordinate moves counter clockwise, like a spiral.

$\vec{a}\cdot\hat{e_\theta}=1$ everywhere. This vector is perpendicular to the vector $\hat{e_r}$ with constant unit magnitude everywhere.

So in the end, you have counter-clockwise spiral with vectors point slightly counter clockwise to the vector pointing directly from the origin to the location.

Comment: That was helpful, thanks! To find the basis spherical basis vectors and interpret the equation algebraically, I find myself using the transform matrix to cartesian system. Is this necessary?

Comment: One complication of curvilinear coordinates is unlike the usual euclidean basis, the basis vectors change from place to place. So a vector in one location could be the same as a vector in another location in terms of magnitude and direction, but because the local basis vectors are different, the vector components are different. So in curvilinear coordinates, vectors are additive only at a point.

Comment: How would you know that $e_r$ and $e_{\theta}$ are perpendicular without converting to cartesian coordinates? Can you derive those basis vectors in absence of the cartesian system?

Comment: Also, what field of math does study of coordinate systems belong to?

Comment: Consider $r$, the distance from the origin as a scalar field. You can take the gradient in non-cartesian coordinates. The gradient points in the direction of greatest assent of $r$ with each component vector pointing in direction of greatest assent. 

So $\partial r / \partial x=\partial \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} /\partial x=x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. $\partial r / \partial r$ = 1. x increases directly in the positive x direction, r increases radially outward, so that gives the direction. 

Arbitrary choice of coordinates need not result in perpendicular basis vectors. They can still be very useful.

Comment: You can use coordinate systems in a lot of paces. Linear Algebra, Vector Calculus, which means all over physics. It's especially important in General Relativity. Relevant concepts popup in engineering, whether aerospace or anything where material properties are important.